# How to avoid creation of xml tag for properties which has the value Nothing in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, wcf-binding

Suppose i have a service, where i give some input , and i am setting the properties of Name and Age as Nothing 
Name and Age are nullable types.
Now as Name and Age are nothing i do not want a xml tag generated in the output.But below xml tags are generated with nil=true.

```
 <Name xsi:nil="true"/> 
 <Age xsi:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: Why do you care? Do you really need to save space to that extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the way WCF serialize objects. Take a look here [here](http://www.netknowledgenow.com/blogs/onmaterialize/archive/2007/01/18/Control-WCF-Serialization-of-Collections-with-IXmlSerializable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `IsRequired` and `EmitDefaultValue` properties of the `DataContract` attribute to false:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public byte? Age { get; set; }
```